# Conversion of CSV file in MyGeoData Converter - XY columns not recognized

Tags: convert, coordinates, csv, format

Recently I have tried to import various CSV files with XY coordinates to [MyGeoData Converter](http://converter.mygeodata.eu). In some cases I got a message:

> Selected data does not have a spatial part!

For example, this file works fine:

```
id,name,coordx,coordy
1,Start,18.63,49.5
2,End,18.65,49.42
```

Within this file I am able to see correct extent in the map, assign coordinate system and transform to desired coordinate system and format, but I got a wrong result with this file (no spatial part detected):

```
id,name,koordinatenx,koordinateny
1,Start,18.25,41.16
2,End,18.26,41.12
```

Seems like columns with XY coordinates were not recognized.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

There is a **rule** for detection of columns containing coordinates **based on attribute name**. Coordinate column is detected if the attribute name of X coordinate is:

```
x, xcoord, xcoordinate, coordx, coordinatex, longitude, long
```

or the attribute name contains:

```
x_*, *_x
```

Similar for Y coordinate:

```
y, ycoord, ycoordinate, coordy, coordinatey, latitude, lat
```

or the attribute name contains:

```
y_*, *_y
```

**Rename** *koordinatenx*, *koordinateny* attributes for example to *x*, *y* or *long*, *lat* - then it should work...